# Layout Editor Continues to crash after Eclipse Reinstall and Java upgrade

Tags: layout, editor

I've been ripping my hair out for the last two days trying to figure this out.  Everytime I open the Eclipse Android Layout Editor, Eclipse crashes.  I've reinstalled Eclipse, made sure I have the latest Java Developer Kit, and I followed previous posts' advice on changing the eclipse.ini file.

AFter reinstalling Eclipse, now when I try to open a new project, it crashes.  Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure it out after help from a very intelligent friend.  We reinstalled the video card drivers and it worked!!!  I spent 12 hours trying to figure this out.  Anyway - I've posted this answer under another similar post, so please don't flame me for repeating myself.